Capturing all the response status of the requests made by page using Playwright
I am using playwright java 1.44v. I am loading a page using page.setContent(htmlString) method. The htmlString is a autosubmit html form. This page contains more than 10 url and these urls can results in html page which can contain more urls.
I want to capture all the requests and wait until I get the response (halt the current thread) status all the http calls made by the page.
Is there any better way to do this in playwright.
Thought of using page.waitForResponse, but it does not fit with my use case.
one way if to use page.onRequest and capture all request in a List and then fetch response/status on request object, but how would I know that page has made all the http calls ?
Imp point is I want to to pause the thread execution till I get the response status all the requests made by page.
Once I get the resposne status all the threads, will proceed with further execution.

Please share a [mcve]. Thanks.
